# Getting current URI in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am aware that in the previous versions of Laravel (e.g. 4), one could get the current uri through

```php
Route::current()->uri();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in Laravel 5.7 or later. I am wondering how it should be rewritten. 
Please note that I am accessing the uri in a blade view and hence cannot use non-static methods.

Comment: URI is a more generic term that covers URLs (including other things). In the context of a webpage there's no difference between URI and URL

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get current url in laravel using folling methods.

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```

Each of these methods may also be accessed via the URL facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

echo URL::current();
```

For more information you can read full documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#accessing-the-current-url).

Answer (score 6):

That should still work - but it may not work as expected if the current path is not named. You should probably instead get the path from the request.

```php
Request::path();
```

It's probably also checking the API of the request instance as there are a number of related methods you can call on it.

```php
Request::root();
Request::url();
Request::fullUrl();
Request::fullUrlWithQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request)
{
    return view('your-view', [ 'current-uri' => $request->route()->uri() ]);
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_uri)

Comment: Yes, but I cannot call `url()->current()->uri()`.